# Dax filter table desc with running total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table with profit, dev_num

I want to filter that table desc by profit column where running sum of dev_num =<30

i mean sth like this:

Profit | Dev_num

1000000   10

100000    10

340000     6

240000     4

do you know maybe how i should build my measure for this calculated table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DAX can be like below :

```
EVALUATE
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( 'yourTable'[Profit] ),
            "Dev_num", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'yourTable'[Dev_num]) )
        ),
        [Dev_num] <= 30
    )
    ORDER BY 'yourTable'[Profit]
```